# How to boot my ARM Windows PC (Miix 630) with Android?

Tags: multi-boot, android, lenovo-laptop, arm

I have the ARM based Lenovo Miix 630 Windows 10 ARM PC/laptop/tablet with the Snapdragon 835 processor

I'd love to dual boot into Android though or install Android at all on there. Android is normally compatible with ARM processors, so how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Have you tried it? Have you done any research on this?

Answer (score 2):

There's a forum post for the Miix 320 saying it's not possible because no drivers have been written by Intel for Android on the devices: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Windows-based-Tablets/Miix-320-Android-support/m-p/4439522#M12398

However, there's a project out there building custom Ubuntu (Linux) images for the Miix 630 and a few other similar ARM-based Windows devices, though some rather important features (like WiFi) may not yet be working: https://github.com/aarch64-laptops

So, I'm going to guess that it's possible, but there remains a lot of development work still to do to get Android running on this device, and there is not yet a way to do this.

Comment: I found the Linux versions being developed for my device and will keep an eye on its development.Thanks for the thorough answer. I figured it wouldn't be as easy as booting Android from USB.

The Miix 320 you mentioned does not have an ARM CPU however, it
's an Intel. The user in question wanted to get Android-x86 working, an open source 32bit Android version. The difference is that my processor is running Android on phones natively, a Snapdragon 835 which is also in my Android phone.

I haven't tried it as I don't know where to start. My research shows that this hasn't been asked before